# How can I wrap text into a paragraph of x characters without importing any modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a list of words (lowercase) parsed from an article. I joined them together using .join() with a space into a long string. Punctuation will be treated like words (ie. with spaces before and after).

I want to write this string into a file with at most X characters (in this case, 90 characters) per line, without breaking any words. Each line cannot start with a space or end with a space.

As part of the assignment I am not allowed to import modules, which from my understanding, textwrap would've helped.

I have basically a while loop nested in a for loop that goes through every 90 characters of the string, and firstly checks if it is not a space (ie. in the middle of a word). The while loop would then iterate through the string until it reaches the next space (ie. incorporates the word unto the same line). I then check if this line, minus the leading and trailing whitespaces, is longer than 90 characters, and if it is, the while loop iterates backwards and reaches the character before the word that extends over 90 characters.

```py
x = 0
for i in range(89, len(text), 90):
    while text[i] != " ":
        i += 1
    if len(text[x:i].strip()) > 90:
        while text[i - 1] != " ":
            i = i - 1
    file.write("".join(text[x:i]).strip() + "\n")
    x = i
```

The code works for 90% of the file after comparing with the file with correct outputs. Occasionally there are lines where it would exceed 90 characters without wrapping the extra word into the next line.

EX:

Actual Output on one line (93 chars):

extraordinary thing , but i never read a patent medicine advertisement without being impelled

Expected Output with "impelled" on new line (84 chars + 8 chars):

extraordinary thing , but i never read a patent medicine advertisement without being\nimpelled

Are there better ways to do this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the code work? If so, you are not doing something wrong. If not, please show some specific input, what you expected to get as output, and what you got instead.

Comment: If i’m understanding your explanation correctly, why `.join()` the words only to separate them later anyway?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Well the words are separated in the list, I join them together with spaces into a string to write into the file. It's part of the assignment, and I don't split them later.

Comment: @SpaceFruiticle I explained myself poorly, what I meant is that you have a list of words, join them together, and then iterate to find.... the boundary between each word. If you are required to solve the problem from a single string, not the list of words, then that’s fine!

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I see what you mean, and yeah it would've been better if I could just work with the list first but assignments are assignments and boy are they annoying... Anyway Chris helped me out a bit, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using a "buffer" to hold the data as you build each line to output. As you read each new word check if adding it to the "buffer" would exceed the line length, if it would then you print the "buffer" and then reset the "buffer" starting with the word that couldn't fit in the sentence.

```
data = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis a risus nisi. Nunc arcu sapien, ornare sit amet pretium id, faucibus et ante. Curabitur cursus iaculis nunc id convallis. Mauris at enim finibus, fermentum est non, fringilla orci. Proin nibh orci, tincidunt sed dolor eget, iaculis sodales justo. Fusce ultrices volutpat sapien, in tincidunt arcu. Vivamus at tincidunt tortor. Sed non cursus turpis. Sed tempor neque ligula, in elementum magna vehicula in. Duis ultricies elementum pellentesque. Pellentesque pharetra nec lorem at finibus. Pellentesque sodales ligula sed quam iaculis semper. Proin vulputate, arcu et laoreet ultrices, orci lacus pellentesque justo, ut pretium arcu odio at tellus. Maecenas sit amet nisi vel elit sagittis tristique ac nec diam. Suspendisse non lacus purus. Sed vulputate finibus facilisis."""
sentence_limit = 40
buffer = ""
for word in data.split():
    word_length = len(word)
    buffer_length = len(buffer)

    if word_length > sentence_limit:
        print(f"ERROR: the word '{word}' is longer than the sentence limit of {sentence_limit}")
        break

    if buffer_length + word_length < sentence_limit:
        if buffer:
            buffer += " "
        buffer += word
    else:
        print(buffer)
        buffer = word
print(buffer)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Duis a risus nisi. Nunc
arcu sapien, ornare sit amet pretium id,
faucibus et ante. Curabitur cursus
iaculis nunc id convallis. Mauris at
enim finibus, fermentum est non,
fringilla orci. Proin nibh orci,
tincidunt sed dolor eget, iaculis
sodales justo. Fusce ultrices volutpat
sapien, in tincidunt arcu. Vivamus at
tincidunt tortor. Sed non cursus turpis.
Sed tempor neque ligula, in elementum
magna vehicula in. Duis ultricies
elementum pellentesque. Pellentesque
pharetra nec lorem at finibus.
Pellentesque sodales ligula sed quam
iaculis semper. Proin vulputate, arcu et
laoreet ultrices, orci lacus
pellentesque justo, ut pretium arcu odio
at tellus. Maecenas sit amet nisi vel
elit sagittis tristique ac nec diam.
Suspendisse non lacus purus. Sed
vulputate finibus facilisis.
```

Comment: Thank you for this Chris. It pretty much does exactly what I want it to do, except the last line is missing. Similarly to the example you provided, after "Sed" of the final line, there is "vulputate finibus facilisis." that is missing. Is there an extra statement that I should add to include that line?

Comment: @SpaceFruiticle so are you allowed to split the string or not? What I understood from your comment is that you can't.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yeah I think I'm getting things mixed up. The assignment controls what is inputted into the function, which is a string of words joined together by .join() from a list. However, after that, in the function itself, I can do whatever I want, and Chris has shown that the best way to do this is to split it up again using .split(). So yes, I can split it.

Comment: @SpaceFruiticle Okay, that makes sense. It's much easier that way.

Comment: I liked the buffer idea

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression:

```
import re

with open('f0.txt', 'r') as f:
    # file must be 1 long single line of text)
    text = f.read().rstrip()
    for line in re.finditer(r'(.{1,70})(?:$|\s)', text):
        print(line.group(1))
```

To approach another way without regex:

```
# Constant
J = 70

# output list
out = []

with open('f0.txt', 'r') as f:
    # assumes file is 1 long line of text
    line = f.read().rstrip()

    i = 0

    while i+J < len(line):
        idx = line.rfind(' ', i, i+J)
        if idx != -1:
            out.append(line[i:idx])
            i = idx+1
        else:
            out.append(line[i:i+J] + '-')
            i += J

    out.append(line[i:]) # get ending line portion

for line in out:
    print(line)
```

Here are the file contents (1 long single string):

```
I have basically a while loop nested in a for loop that goes through every 90 characters of the string, and firstly checks if it is not a space (ie. in the middle of a word). The while loop would then iterate through the string until it reaches the next space (ie. incorporates the word unto the same line). I then check if this line, minus the leading and trailing whitespaces, is longer than 90 characters, and if it is, the while loop iterates backwards and reaches the character before the word that extends over 90 characters.
```

Output:

```
I have basically a while loop nested in a for loop that goes through
every 90 characters of the string, and firstly checks if it is not a
space (ie. in the middle of a word). The while loop would then
iterate through the string until it reaches the next space (ie.
incorporates the word unto the same line). I then check if this line,
minus the leading and trailing whitespaces, is longer than 90
characters, and if it is, the while loop iterates backwards and
reaches the character before the word that extends over 90 characters.
```